# respawn service Debian Jessie without inittab

Tags: service, debian, inittab

I've installed the last stable version of Debian (Jessie) and /etc/inittab doesn't exist. I have read the new init system is called Sysv.
I need to launch a service with parameter, I used to add a line in inittab like
u1:23:respawn:/etc/init.d/my_service foreground

I'm trying to add this one with sysvrc-conf -p but I don't know how...

How can I do that without inittab?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Found this question by google, maybe someone else finds this usefull: The new init system for Debian Jessie is systemd. The old way in Debian Wheezy was Sysv with `/etc/inittab`.

To create a respawn service with systemd just create a file in `/etc/systemd/system/` i.e. `mplayer2.service`

```
[Unit]
Desription=mplayer with systemd, respawn
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mplayer -nolirc -ao alsa -vo null -really-quiet http://stream.sunshine-live.de/hq/mp3-128/Facebook-og-audio-tag/
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and activate it

```
systemctl enable mplayer2.service
```

reboot or start it manually

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start mplayer2.service
```

If you reboot or kill the process, it will be restarted automatically some seconds later.